# Генерация точек в label DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Не представляю как решить вот такую задачу: 
В label, при нажатии на кнопку, генерируется диапазон (в порядке возростания) который состоит из знака "-".

То есть место Label знак:

```
-
--
---
----
-----
------
-------
--------
```

Как только дойдет до конца - цикл снова повторяется.

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз сформулировать задачу. В Label на каждое нажатие кнопки должен добавляться символ `-` пока длина строки не превысит некоторой длины. А после превышения строка начинает заполняться заново. Так?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Немного не так. В Label, при нажатии на кнопку, будут генерироваться, в порядке возрастания, строки из символа "-". От 1 и до 8 знаков (Как показано выше. ) И цикл должен постоянно повторяться. То есть сначала знак "-" потом "--" и так далее...

Comment: Чем это отличается от того, что я написал? Или вы хотите, чтобы изменение Label шло непрерывно, без нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Да, нужно именно беспрерывно.

Comment: Таймер, в таймер :=Label.Text + '-', проверить длинну и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
strict private
  FLabel: TLabel;
  FStopEvent: THandle;
strict private
  procedure UpdateLabel;
protected
  procedure Execute;
public
  constructor Create(ALabel: TLabel);
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

constructor Create(ALabel: TLabel);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FLabel := ALabel;
  FStopEvent := CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  SetEvent(FStopEvent);
  inherited Destroy;
  CloseHandle(FStopEvent);
end;

procedure TMyThread.UpdateLabel;
begin
  if Length(FLabel.Caption) > 10 then
    FLabel.Caption := '-'
  else
    FLabel.Caption := FLabel.Caption + '-';
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  LRes: Cardinal;
begin
  repeat
    LRes := WaitForSingleObject(FStopEvent, 1000);
    case LRes of
      WAIT_TIMEOUT: Synchronize(UpdateLabel);
      WAIT_FAILED: RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
  until LRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FThread = nil then
    FThread := TMyThread.Create(Label1)
  else
    FreeAndNil(FThread);
end;
```

---

**Update**

Что-то я под вечер перестал соображать. Есть решение гораздо проще.

На форму бросаем таймер, в свойство `Interval` указываем как часто он должен срабатывать, в обработчике `OnTimer` пишем

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Length(Label1.Caption) > 10 then
    Label1.Caption := '-'
  else
    Label1.Caption := Label1.Caption + '-';
end;
```

В обработчике `OnClick` кнопки пишем

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := not Timer1.Enabled;
end;
```